# how to pass value to where parameter by variable?

Tags: sql-server

when i use a parameter value directly in where it works fine but when i want to pass it by a 
variable it occures a error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.


declare @PostsIds  varchar(50)=N'''2'',''1'''
SELECT       * FROM            mytable
WHERE     id in (@PostsIds)
```

but this query works fine

```
declare @PostsIds  varchar(50)=N'''2'',''1'''
SELECT       * FROM            mytable
WHERE     id in ('2','1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable in an IN clause in a SQL statement.  You could do this in a stored procedure instead:

```
Set @sql='SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id IN (' + @PostsIds + ')'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: That's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your way won't work, because when you pass in that variable, you are passing in a string, not a list which is what `IN` expects. You could get around it by using dynamic SQL i.e. first create the rest of the query as a `nvarchar` variable, append your variable with the list to the where clause and then execute the statement with the statement `sp_executesql`.